# connecting wifi in raspberry pi with wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, wifi

First of all I would like to say I just started working on Raspberry Pi Model B three weeks ago. I am running Raspbian and connected Tenda wifi dongle(RT2870). The very first day I was unable to connect to WiFi. Thinking it was a driver issue, I wasted a lot of time on that. But eventually I got it working by removing wpa_conf line in the /etc/networks/interfaces file.

But two days ago, the internet stopped working still connected to WiFi while rest of the devices were able to connect to internet. Now I have two wifi networks so I tried to connect to the other network but failed to connect to that one even by removing the wpa_conf line and directly providing the SSID and password in the /etc/network/interfaces file. So as I had no other option, I was back to figuring out what is wrong with the wpa_supplicant file. I have been on it for last two days. Reading and trying solutions for this site and many other. So I am hoping to get a hint at what might be the problem. Willing to try any suggestion.

Now what is happening?

**sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart (and) sudo ifup wlan0**

gives me the same error

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
```

**sudo iwlist scan | grep ESSID**

gives the list of the nearby wifi networks which means the wifi dongle and the driver is working fine but not connecting to it using wpa_supplicant file.

**Contents of wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="****"
psk="**"
proto=WPA
key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
pairwise=TKIP
group=TKIP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

**Contents of /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

#address 192.168.1.16
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.1.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 4.4.4.4
#wpa-ssid ***
#wpa-psk ***
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

I was using static ip when everything was working. When the internet stopped working I added the dns-nameservers line. But with no luck.

I had tried dhcp mode as well to connect to the second network. 
Also tried wpa-roam(with manual) and wpa-conf(with dhcp).
I had also edited /etc/resolv.conf file writing different nameservers.

So this is where I am stuck with a working connecting network with no internet and another network that I cant connect.

Comment: It looks to me like your problem is due to a syntax error in your wpa_supplicant.conf file. To identify it, I suggest you add the parms one by one until you find the error.

Comment: As regards the bigger issue of network connectivity, can you just let me know the current rating (Amps) of your power supply ?

Comment: @IanB The power supply wouldnt be the problem because I am using 5V 2A supply. And you were right there was some syntax error in my wpa_supplicant file. But still it didnt solve the primary issue of getting connected. But when I do the network restart or ifup command, it just gives me the first two errors.
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1

Comment: @IanB Guess what. The network connected and internet started working. Not sure how. But the commands still give me those errors. So some other way, the network is working. I would still like to understand what the problem is so that I dont run into this again in the future. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: No prob ... thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you be more specific from next time while posting. Like which distro you are using and which wifi dongle do you have etc.

as I can figure out

> Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

is a issue

so you can look into this [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/failed-to-connect-to-wpa_supplicant-wpa_ctrl_open-no-such-file-or-directory-611577/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I am asking a question here. Editing the question.